# Rails scopes with multiple arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, filtering, named-scopes

In my offer.rb model I am doing some filtering after clients who have these offers.
But I want to be able to pass another param in my scope to search by, for example, the age of a client or so.

This is what I have now in my offer model:

```
scope :with_client_id, lambda { |client_id| where(:client_id => client_id) }
```

In the view:

```
<%= f.select(:with_client_id, options_for_select(current_partner.clients.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}), { include_blank: true}) %>
```

How can I pass a client's age per say in this scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Two Options

#### Using a "splat"

```
scope :with_client_id_and_age, lambda { |params| where(:client_id => params[0], :age => params[1]) }
```

And then you'd have to call it with:

```
Offer.with_client_id_and_age( client_id, age )
```

#### Using a params hash

```
scope :with_client_id_and_age, lambda { |params| where(:client_id => params[:client_id], :age => params[:age]) }
```

And then you'd have to call it with:

```
Offer.with_client_id_and_age( { client_id: client_id, age: age } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I left the scope unchanged and just modified the select in the view:

```
<%= f.select(:with_client_id, options_for_select(current_partner.clients.collect{|c| [c.name_and_age, c.id]}), { include_blank: true}) %>
```

With the name_and_age method in the clients controller:

```
def name_and_age
  [name, age].compact.join " "
end
```

I can type some age too in the select2 box to make the filterring.